# Fix Drupal 6 menu urls on test server

Tags: drupal-6

After restoring a database dump from my Drupal 6 website on a testserver, all menu links link to the original Drupal website instead of the local testserver.
I have tried clearing all caches without result. How can I make the menu links point to my local test server?

Comment: Are you sure that the menu paths aren't actually full URLs?

Comment: Yes. They are relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

Truncate (empty) the `cache_menu` table. In phpMyAdmin, select your database in the sidebar, then the table, then scroll down and click 'Empty the table (TRUNCATE)'.

The SQL statement would be `TRUNCATE cache_menu;`.

I assume that you have a backup of the db since you've done a migration. If not, **back up the db first**.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The i18n module had the url of the original website as url for the main (default) language. Clearing this setting, results in the expected behavior.

Because this setting was not cleared when the i18n module was disabled, I had a hard time finding the this cause.